# XMLHttpRequest - flickr - cross origin header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, flickr

just having a play with the Flickr API and seem to be unable to successfully claw anything out of it.

I tried using Jquery code below

```
var flickrURL = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=jsoncallback=?";
var flickrOptions = {
    tags: "cats",
    format: "json"
}
var ajaxCallback = function(data){
    console.log(data);
};
$.getJSON(flickrURL, flickrOptions, ajaxCallback);
```

I also tried the old vanilla route

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=jsoncallback=?");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
xhr.send();
```

I have used AJAX/XMLrequest successful but not with an API. The when the vanilla fails I'm getting 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header' which I don't understand since it's meant to be an open feed and with the Jquery I'm getting 'jsonFlickrFeed is not defined'. Both of which I find very puzzling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to do minor changes

```
var flickrURL = 

"https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=jsoncallback=?";

var flickrOptions = {
    tags: "cats",
    format: "json"
}

var jsonFlickrFeed = function(data){
    console.log(data);
};

$.getJSON(flickrURL, flickrOptions);
```

Flickr response looks for **jsonFlickrFeed** function which was not defined in your case.

https://codepen.io/smtgohil/pen/ZXeYqB?editors=0010

You can check the console for output.

Comment: Thanks man, I also discovered off the back of your comment that the vanilla method simply involves loading the script into the page and allowing it to call the jsonFlickrFeed as you mentioned

Comment: Yup.. .happy coding .. :D

Answer (score 1):

Sumeets answer is correct but just thought I'd post my vanilla solution off the back of that.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
var jsonFlickrFeed = function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```